# Event binding for keyboard input or change through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field with id `myinput` , and have `change` event bind to this field through,

```
$("input#myinput").change(function(){ 
  alert("the value is changed");
}
```

But the handler is not getting called, if I change the value through javascript

```
$("input#myinput").val(text);
```

But, it works if I enter the input through keyboard.

so, it seems like I am binding to wrong event. What should I do to bind to both keyboard input and JS value update (jQuery `val()` here).

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`change` is triggered only by user events. With jQuery you can use [`trigger('change')`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) to trigger the `change` event programatically.

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/raXQx/).